# SMO.Transfer: cannot convert type "database" to type "database"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo, server.transfer

Here is a powershell script:

```
[string] $server   = "devserver\mssql";          # SQL Server Instance
[string] $database = "ftg";      # Database with the tables to script out.
[string] $folder   = "d:\FT\FTProject\";          # Path to export to
[string] $SQLLogin = "Sa";
[string] $SQLPass  = "Sa1234";

# Reference to SMO
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO');

Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss) + ": Started ...");

$con = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($server, $SQLLogin, $SQLPass);
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server($con);
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database($srv, $database);


#Use SMO Transfer Class by specifying source database
#you can specify properties you want either brought over or excluded, when the copy happens
$ObjTransfer   = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Transfer;
$ObjTransfer.Database = $db
```

At last line an error occurs:

Exception setting "Database": "Cannot convert the "[ftg]" value of type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Managem
ent.Smo.Database"."
At D:\FT\FTProject\Setup\transfer.ps1:31 char:1
+ $ObjTransfer.Database = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database] $db
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

I also tryed to set $db as follows:

```
$db = $srv.Databases[$database]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$db = $srv.Databases[$database]
...
$ObjTransfer = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Transfer -ArgumentList $db
```

This should create the Transfer object using `$db` as the Source Database.

See example at [MSDN: Transferring Schema and Data from One Database to Another in PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162563.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't works too. Error occurs:

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Transfer" and the argument count: "1".
At D:\FT\FTProject\Setup\transfer.ps1:25 char:18
+ $ObjTransfer   = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Transfe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.

I also tryed an expample from your link - same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because different versions of Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll were loaded.

I get the same error when i loaded first assembly in 10 version and another one in 12.

When i loaded both of them explicitly in the same version everything worked fine.

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"

Add-Type -path "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunatelly I can not test this solution ))